# Assign array object with value then multiply that value by the count of matching objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have manipulated my array by assigning a value to a matching string. I now want to multiply the count of that string with the value I assigned.

Here is my array output:

```
0: {gameScore: "R", reportDate: "2018-05-09", value: 2}
1: {gameScore: "M", reportDate: "2018-01-09", value: 1}
2: {gameScore: "M+", reportDate: "2018-02-09", value: 1.5}
3: {gameScore: "M+", reportDate: "2018-01-09", value: 1.5}
4: {gameScore: "M+", reportDate: "2018-02-09", value: 1.5}
```

I have assigned the gameScore a value:

```
const SCORES = {
    'R': 2,
    'M': 1,
    'M+': 1.5,
}
```

I want to get the total number of matching objects e.g. "M+" = 3 then multiply this by the initial value I set of `'M+': 1.5,` so `"M+"` will ultimately be `'4.5'`

```
var calculation = _(observations)
          .filter(observation => {
            return (
                moment(observation.reportDate).year() == moment().subtract('years', 1).year() && moment(observation.reportDate).month() > moment().subtract('years', 1).month()) ||
              (moment(observation.reportDate).year() == moment().year() && moment(observation.reportDate).month() < moment().month());
          })
          .omitBy(x => x.gameScore === "NULL")
          .map(observation => ({ ...observation,
            value: SCORES[observation.gameScore]
          }))
          .value();
```

I am assuming that I need to do something with value: `SCORES[observation.gameScore]` to get the amount of objects and do the multiplication before it gets to this point?

Here is a fiddle with the other calculations already being used: https://jsfiddle.net/xdtk2gn6/

Using lodash & ES6

Comment: Hi, you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/npajzu5s/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for that :

```js
const data = [
{gameScore: "R", reportDate: "2018-05-09", value: 2},
{gameScore: "M", reportDate: "2018-01-09", value: 1},
{gameScore: "M+", reportDate: "2018-02-09", value: 1.5},
{gameScore: "M+", reportDate: "2018-01-09", value: 1.5},
{gameScore: "M+", reportDate: "2018-02-09", value: 1.5}
];

const SCORES = {
    'R': 2,
    'M': 1,
    'M+': 1.5,
};

let result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.gameScore] = acc[curr.gameScore] || 0; //Init value to 0 if it doesn't exist
  acc[curr.gameScore] += curr.value*SCORES[curr.gameScore]; //Add the current value * SCORE
  return acc;
},{});
console.log(result);
```